# How to get color name in PanelColorSettings in custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I am developing a custom Gutenberg block with the PanelColorSettings component to set up the background color, here is my code

```
<PanelColorSettings
                    title={ __( 'Color Settings' ) }
                    colorSettings={ [
                        {
                            value: backgroundColor,
                            onChange: ( colorValue ) => setAttributes( { backgroundColor: colorValue } ),
                            label: __( 'Background Color' ),
                        },
                    ] }
                >

                </PanelColorSettings>
```

How do I the color name instead of the color code for the backgroundColor attribute? It seems the default returned value is the color code which is useless in future color code updates as the content would need to be re-saved.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it with the function getColorObjectByColorValue ([take a look at the gutenberg files](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/9297fc93a2c7b47575007127ffe038d22101de81/packages/editor/src/components/colors/utils.js)).

If you have something like

```
const backgroundColors = [
        {
            name: 'Light Green',
            slug: 'light-green',
            color: '#E6F0F0'
        },
        {
            name: 'Light Gray',
            slug: 'light-gray',
            color: '#F7F7F7'
        }
    ];
```

then you can get the color name by

```
const test = getColorObjectByColorValue(backgroundColors, backgroundColor);
console.log(test.name);
```

Should also work with the default palette.

Comment: It would be great to see an example of using this in block with `onChange` and `setAttributes`.
I mean i know `getColorObjectByColorValue` is a good direction but I'm having trouble implementing it in a block

Answer (score 1):

thanks to: https://javascriptforwp.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-a-color-class-name/ , Note: wp.editor.getColorObjectByColorValue is deprecated now using wp.blockEditor.getColorObjectByColorValue

```
   const { select } = wp.data;
   const { getColorObjectByColorValue} = wp.blockEditor;

    function onChangeColor ( color ) {
        colorName = '';
        if( color ) {
            const settings = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditorSettings();
            const colorObject = getColorObjectByColorValue( settings.colors, color );
            if( colorObject ) {
                colorName = colorObject.slug;
            }
        }
        props.setAttributes({color: color});
        props.setAttributes({colorName: colorName});

    }
```